# How can I improve my absolute import statements?

Tags: python, python-import, importerror

I am busy with selenium webdriver automation using python but I am having problems simplifying my import statements.

The path to my 'create_task.py' file where I am doing my imports is `'/home/test/Documents/Internal_Dev/internal_automation/project_1/Project_Tab/Project/Tasks/create_task.py'`.

The simplest solution that worked for me was to do the absolute imports as follows:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/home/test/Documents/Internal_Dev/internal_automation')
from project_1.Login import login
from project_1.Project_Tab.Project.Tasks import task_web_elements
from project_1.Wait_Methods.wait_for_loading_overlay import WaitForLoadingOverlay
```

Whenever I try to import using only

```
from project_1.Login import login
from project_1.Project_Tab.Project.Tasks import task_web_elements
from project_1.Wait_Methods.wait_for_loading_overlay import WaitForLoadingOverlay
```

I get the following error `'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'project_1'.`

Is there a way to simplify this as I can't figure out why it is necessary for me to include the

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/home/test/Documents/Internal_Dev/internal_automation')
```

as I am starting my absolute imports from the root directory/package of my project.

Comment: If you would put the main script (with which you start the program) in `/home/test/Documents/Internal_Dev/internal_automation`, this path would be added to `sys.path` automatically.

Comment: you should *package your project so that it is installable* then install it with `pip`. Then you won't need to worry about the path ("installing" means the library is put into the default search path, in site-modules directory that corresponds to the interpreter, which is always in `sys.path`)

Comment: Dankie meneer jy het 'n fantastiese idee gegee wat my dag in meervoud verbeter het

Answer (score 0):

use the file location to determine the root directory. you can use print to see the path.

```
import os
abspath = os.path.abspath(__file__)
filename = os.sep.join(abspath.split(os.sep)[-2:])
abspath = abspath.replace(filename, "")
import sys
sys.path.append(abspath)
```

or

```
import os
abspath = os.path.abspath(__file__)
filename = abspath.split(os.sep)[-1]
abspath = abspath.replace(filename, "")
import sys
sys.path.append(abspath)
```